# Is there something incorrect within the documentation of % operator when applied to string formatting?

Tags: python, documentation, python-3.5

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting) is the description of the old style string formatting, within which octal and hexadecimal values conversion are prescribed.
I've experimented with the syntax, however something unexpected occurred.

Code `'%#07x' % 1223` and `'%#07o' % 1223` had the similar format of results, which were **'0x004c7'** and **'0o02307'** respectively. However the associated description about octal values mismatched with the behavior.

> The alternate form causes a leading zero ('0') to be inserted between left-hand padding and the formatting of the number if the leading character of the result is not already a zero.

All code are executed within the Interactive interpreter of **CPython** with the version **`3.5.2`**.

Comment: yeah the documentation seems outdated.

Comment: I'd suggest that you [submit a bug report](https://docs.python.org/3.6/bugs.html#documentation-bugs) so that this can get updated...

Comment: I did it,and i received a positive response ,but I'm not sure whether it represented the official voice or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had reported the issue to the Python community，and the bug was already fixed.The previous description has been changed into the correct one.
See the [Notes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting) section,row 1.